# call lua callback with custom data as function argument

Tags: c++, callback, lua

I'm just looking for solution how to pass object from C to lua callback as function argument, is it even possible? I cannot find any referece. just trying something like this:

```
luabind::call_function(State, "Callback_name", object);
```

but luabind is not  a option in this case because it is obsolete and additionally some features just don't work that's probably because of boost as I read but don't know exactly, thats why I switched to toLua++ but still cannot find any solution for it. I'm just trying to achieve to access data from C in lua callback ex:

```
function LUA_Callback(object1, object2)
    print(object1.name)
    print(object2.size)
end
```

Is there any way to solve it or library(without boost) to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "push object". It's trivial to push numbers, strings, C functions, tables, etc. -- in other words, Lua objects -- using API routines like `lua_pushstring`, `lua_pushnumber`, etc.

If you're talking about pushing C++ objects, you need to create and push [userdata](http://www.lua.org/pil/28.1.html). If you want them to behave like objects from Lua, then you'll need the appropriate metatable/methods.

Comment: Yeah, I want to push C++ objects and I want to to behave them like objects in Lua too, could you give me any reference about that? Thanks.